# MultiClient Chat Server

Tags: java, sockets, chat

So I am still new to networking in Java, and most of this is confusing, specifically Threaded Servers. I made a simple Socket Chat Program about a week of two ago, but I wanted to expand it but having multiple clients and auto server detection on lan (via broadcast or manually pinging each ip/port). But this week I am mainly focusing on multiple clients, aka having a multiple threaded server. This is the code I have so far but its buggy, where the server only sends/receive messages to the second client, and the first client was only able to send one message before the server ignored it. My Goal is to have this server support about 10-20 clients.

```
package org.codingllamas.Chat;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;

public class SC {

static Socket clientSocket;
static BufferedReader inFromServer;
static BufferedWriter outToServer;

public static void clientSetup(int port,String ip) throws IOException, BadLocationException {
     String incomingSentence;
     Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>Connected to </b>" + ip + ":" + port + "<br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
     clientSocket = new Socket(ip,port);
     while (true) {
         inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
         incomingSentence = inFromServer.readLine();     
         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
         Start.window.requestFocus();
         Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>Server: </b>" + incomingSentence + "<br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
     }
}

public static void clientSend(String msg) throws IOException, BadLocationException{
    outToServer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
    outToServer.write(msg + "\r\n");
    outToServer.flush();
    outToServer.write(msg + "\r\n");
    outToServer.flush();
    Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>You: </b>" + msg + "<br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
}

static ServerSocket welcomeSocket;
static Socket connectionSocket;
static BufferedReader inFromClient;
static BufferedWriter outToClient;

public static void secondClient() throws IOException{

    connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();


}

public static void serverSetup(int port) throws Exception {
    welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>Server Started on port: " + port + "</b><br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
    connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                secondClient();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot send message");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    String clientSentence;
    while(true){       
        inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        Start.window.requestFocus();
        Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>Parther: </b>" + inFromClient.readLine() + "<br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
   }
}

public static void serverSend(String msg) throws IOException, BadLocationException {
    outToClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()));
    outToClient.write(msg + "\r\n");
    outToClient.flush();
    Start.kit.insertHTML(Start.doc,Start.doc.getLength(),"<b>You: </b>" + msg + "<br>",0,0,HTML.Tag.B);
}
}
```

Comment: Not all of your methods should be static, you should take advantage of the object orientation of java.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org/).)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to be able to have multiple clients, you should create a thread with the main purpose of waiting for and accepting connections.

You should next probably have an object for clients, so they can easily store their socket and be placed into an array. Within this client object, you can create threads for sending and receiving data, and the clients individual in/out streams.

This will make your program expandable into multiple clients, and make it easier to handle all of the clients.

Comment: how would I achieve this? I know that you can use a hashmap for the storing of the client number and the thread associated with it. But how do I send a message to all of the clients? I don't exactly know send (access a method) on a certain thread

Comment: @DarkLlama If you have a client object that contains your output streams, its as simple as iterating through an array of all your client objects and calling a method in your client class to write the data to its output stream.